# Sequelize getting unknown column in belongsToMany association

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, associations

I have three models `Channel`, `ChannelUser` & `Conversation`. I'm trying to get all conversations from the `Channel` model but I ran into an unknown column issue *(SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Conversations->ChannelUser.ConversationId' in 'field list')*.

These are the association I'm using in models,

**Channel Model**

```js
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init(
            {
                name: DataTypes.STRING(),
            },
            {
                sequelize,
                freezeTableName: true
            }
        );
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.channelUser = this.hasMany(models.channelUser, { foreignKey: 'channelId' });
        this.conversation = this.belongsToMany(models.conversation, {
            through: {
                model: models.channelUser
            },
            foreignKey: 'channelId',
            otherKey: 'id'
        });
    }
```

**ChannelUser Model**

```js
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init(
            {
            },
            {
                sequelize,
                freezeTableName: true
            }
        );
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.channel = this.belongsTo(models.channel, { foreignKey: 'channelId' });
        this.user = this.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
        this.conversation = this.hasMany(models.conversation, {
            foreignKey: 'channelUserId',
        });
    }
```

**Conversation Model**

```js
    static init(sequelize, DataTypes) {
        return super.init(
            {
                message: DataTypes.TEXT()
            },
            {
                sequelize,
                freezeTableName: true
            }
        );
    }

    static associate(models) {
        this.channelUser = this.belongsTo(models.channelUser, { foreignKey: 'channelUserId' });
    }
```

I'm also sharing the ER diagram for reference,

[image: ER diagram reference]

These are the sources I took for reference

1. [Sequelize Find belongsToMany Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959073/sequelize-find-belongstomany-association)
2. [Sequelize findAll with belongsToMany association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184399/sequelize-findall-with-belongstomany-association)
3. [How to disambiguate between multiple associations between the same models in Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647236/how-to-disambiguate-between-multiple-associations-between-the-same-models-in-seq)
4. https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html
5. https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/associations/belongs-to-many/

Comment: show your model definitions

Comment: @Anatoly I have updated code snippet with the model definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the way I see it is, you have a bad belongsToMany join in here... that assumes many to many and you don’t have that... The channel user table should only join channel and user... the you should have a user conversation join table that is many to many... and a channel itself would just be a hasMany on conversation since a conversation can actually only belong to one channel.